# Right to Left ProgressBar?

Tags: android, view, progress-bar

Does anyone know how to make a View reversed, I have a horizontal ProgressBar and I want it to right to left instead of left to right

Comment: What language? What platform? What API?

Comment: Why do you need an RTL progress bar? All the progress bars I've seen go from left to right.

Comment: We can only answer pseudocode questions with pseudocode... otherwise please at least specify what EboMike's comment asks for.

Comment: Oh sorry, I swear I put Android. It's just for a game.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make a subclass of the normal progress bar view and implement the onDraw method to rotate the canvas before drawing it:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(180,<CenterX>,<CenterY>);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 72):

It's even easier. You can simply call the following method and then it's rotated and works just how you wanted.

```
progressBar.setRotation(180);
```

An example:
[image: a normal progressbar and a RTL progressbar]

Comment: should be the best answer so far

Comment: You can set this directly in the XML file with `android:rotation="180"`

Comment: It also crashes my app. Android 6.0. Default direction is RTL, but I wanted the progress bar LTR.

Comment: Setting the `LayoutDirection` on ProgressBar object works for me.

Comment: In API 24 (7.0) seekbar become transparent with rotation=180

Answer (score 34):

You can flip a view in xml using scaleX or scaleY attributes

```
    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="-1"/>
```

Comment: definitely should be the answer

Comment: available in circle ProgressBar

Answer (score 14):

```
 public class inverseSeekBar extends ProgressBar {

public inverseSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public inverseSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public inverseSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     canvas.save(); 

        //now we change the matrix
        //We need to rotate around the center of our text
        //Otherwise it rotates around the origin, and that's bad. 
        float py = this.getHeight()/2.0f;
        float px = this.getWidth()/2.0f;
        canvas.rotate(180, px, py); 

        //draw the text with the matrix applied. 
        super.onDraw(canvas); 

        //restore the old matrix. 
        canvas.restore(); 
}}
  <com.hlidskialf.android.widget.inverseSeekBar 

       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:secondaryProgress="75" 

/>
```

mypackage: com.test.testProgressBar

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to rotate the entire `View`.

Just use [a single xml attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html#attr_android%3agravity) in your `my_progress_drawable.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_background"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:drawable="@drawable/my_right_to_left_progress"
            android:gravity="right" /> <!-- Clip the image from the RIGHT -->
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) tells us that `gravity="right"` does this:

> Put the object at the right edge of its container, not changing its size. When clipOrientation is "horizontal", clipping occurs at the left side of the drawable.

Don't override `onDraw()`. This implementation is more stable across different versions of Android.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to set the gravity of a `ClipDrawable` programmatically without invoking its [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html#ClipDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: For holo themes which use <scale> rather than <clip>, scaleGravity can be used instead

Answer (score 8):

if you want it in XML there are two properties you can use.
if you want to use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` it requires minimum API 17 but if you use `android:rotation="180"` there is no API limitation

```
<ProgressBar
        android:progress="20"
        android:rotation="180"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Cos I'm lazy I just add these two lines to the `seekbar` xml:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:mirrorForRtl="true"
```

Any downsides to this?

Comment: mirrorforRtl only supports api > 18

Comment: This must be the right answer if anyone is looking to switch between rtl and ltr layouts.
If you want both that for LTR the progress should start from left and for RTL progress should start from right just add ->
android:mirrorForRtl="true"

Answer (score 3):

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:progress="80" />
```