# Mirror (flip) a View / ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar, material-components-android, progress-indicator

I have a custom built circular progress bar used for a seconds counter on a clock, which I'd like to flip, so that the clock is counting counter-clockwise.

Searching here for a solution, I found this:

[Right to Left ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877823/right-to-left-progressbar)

Which obviously works for a horizontal progress bar, but I can't simply rotate it 180 degrees, since that will just move the clock 180 degrees and it will still be ticking clockwise.

Is there any other way to mirror a ProgressBar, or any View?

Edit:

Just found "android:rotationY" and the programmatic equivalent, but this ideally needs to be for 2.2 and above..

Comment: This is not really an answer, but would you consider open sourcing the circular progressbar? I've seen a lot of requests for it.

Comment: This is how I originally did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar/12905405 but a lot has changed on it since then. I can put together a sample application on github after the holidays!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android custom circular ProgressBar direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884317/android-custom-circular-progressbar-direction)

Answer (score 10):

I was able to flip `ProgressBar` simply with attribute `scaleX` in XML:

```
android:scaleX="-1"
```

This works for other `View` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Extend ProgressBar in the same way you would for a horizontal progress bar, but in the onDraw method, flip the canvas rather than rotate it:

```
public class InverseProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

public InverseProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public InverseProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public InverseProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, super.getWidth() * 0.5f, super.getHeight() * 0.5f);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In newer versions of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases), the circular progress bar can be mirrored:

- in the layout with this attribute

  ```
  app:indicatorDirectionCircular
  ```
- or programmatically with this method

  ```
  setIndicatorDirection()
  ```

Refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#types) for more info.