# Android custom circular ProgressBar direction

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-progressbar, progress-indicator

I have a custom Circular Progressbar. This is the drawable I have for it to be determinate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
        android:useLevel="true">
     <gradient
          android:centerColor="#999999"
          android:endColor="#999999"
          android:startColor="#999999"
          android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
   <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="270"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="270">

  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
      android:useLevel="true">


    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:endColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:startColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:type="sweep" />

      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want it to show the progress in a clockwise direction, but now it's showing counterclockwise.

How do I change it?

Comment: how are you incrementing progress? I have a circular progress bar, used your drawable, and it rotates clockwise

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you're using an rtl language? You can force the progress bar to an ltr or clockwise direction by setting the `layoutDirection` property on your `ProgressBar`.

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    android:layoutDirection="ltr" />
```

Answer (score 2):

By using latest versions of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases), you can achieve this:

- in the layout with this attribute

  ```
  app:indicatorDirectionCircular
  ```
- or programmatically with this method

  ```
  setIndicatorDirection()
  ```

Refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#types) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
```

to

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It was that way at the beginning, and I tried changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, but just try to set `android:toDegrees="-360"` like this :

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="-360" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change rotation on Y axis by 180 degrees

```
android:rotationY="180"
```