# Android throttle bar

Tags: android

I have written a little android app for my remote control car, that allows me to use a Nvidia Shield to control it. That app works fine and the controls are all good, but I wanted to add a bar, that shows the percent of the turning on the android screen.

So basically, I want a bar, with a line in the middle that is the zero point. Then when you turn left it will fill in the left side of the bar, starting from the middle, the amount of the turning value. (Which is a value from -1 to 1 for left and right.

Where should I start with this in Android? I realize that I am going to have to make a new class to do this, but could someone give me a general idea of what would be required?

Many Thanks
sub_server

Comment: This sounds like a completely awesome project.  Your question is general enough so that it might be hard to get a good answer on SO.  If this doesn't work ou, I'd be pretty interested in getting involved  Drop me an e-mail (should be easy to find)

Answer (score 0):

I would place two [progress bars](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html) end to end and rotate one so that they both go from the center outwards. See the second answer on this post for rotating a progress bar [rotating progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877823/right-to-left-progressbar)