# A Right to left Progressbar

Tags: delphi

Can anybody help me that how i can set a Progressbar righttoleft in delphi (in win). (ie it start from right side and finish in left side.
I find [Something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877823/right-to-left-progressbar) for android but I can't use it for win.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can you not use the same technique as in the link?
FMX components have a property to rotate them.
Alternatively, you can decrease the value of the progressbar instead of increasing it. Eg. If your progress bar goes from 0 to 100, you can start from 100 and go to 0

Comment: Just going from 100 to 0 won't make the bar start at the right side.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Why is that?

Comment: If it is not rotated, 100%  shows a full progressbar from left to right, while 50% goes from left to the middle. It does not go from middle to right.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes yes I got it. The "completed" part will still be from left to right. Sorry for this

Comment: Not too hard to custom draw such a component.

Comment: @David: if you want it to look themed, or at least like a proper standard control for the platform, it is not too trivial either.

Comment: @rudy actually still trivial using theme api

Comment: @David: Easy to say, but usually not so easy to do, IME.

Comment: One important question: FireMonkey (FMX) or VCL?

Comment: thank all my friends. yes simply goes from 100 to 0 isn't a good solution.  I want it in vcl so i can't use FMX.

Comment: Have you started learning how to write custom components? That's the way forward.